# How can you make a service send a page on one host and send an emai on another in Groundwork / Nagios?

Tags: nagios

We have pre-production servers and production servers. If a service check fails on pre-production, we just want to send an email (no pager). If it fails on a production server, we should send a page.

I know you can change the contact group of a service, but can you change it depending on what host it's running on?

Answer (score 1):

In your Contact.cfg create 2 groups:

```
    define contactgroup{
            contactgroup_name       alert_Email
            service_notification_commands   notify-service-by-email
            alias                   Alert temrerature group
            members                 user1, user2
            }

    define contactgroup{
            contactgroup_name       alert_Email_SMS
            service_notification_commands   notify-service-by-email,notify-service-by-sms
            alias                   Alert temrerature group
            members                 user1, user2
            }
```

And in your host conf (or template depend how you set nagios up) just put the correct group
ex:

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       BladeCenter_test
        service_description             SSH
        check_command                   check_ssh
        contact_groups                  alert_Email
        }

define service{
        use                             generic-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       BladeCenter
        service_description             SSH
        check_command                   check_ssh
        contact_groups                  alert_Email_SMS
        }
```